# Apply a function to particular rows

Tags: r

I want to apply the following code to only the first 3 rows (if it's applied to the second 3, it fails to parse. `netflix_and_disney$release_year <-year(dmy(netflix_and_disney$release_year))`

Is there a way about doing this with this df?

`structure(list(show_id = c("00147800", "07019028", "00115433",  "70234439", "80058654", "80125979"), title = c("10 Things I Hate About You", "101 Dalmatian Street", "101 Dalmatians", "Transformers Prime",  "Transformers: Robots in Disguise", "#realityhigh"), type = c("Movie",  "Tv Show", "Movie", "Tv Show", "Tv Show", "Movie"), rating = c("PG-13",  "N/A", "G", "TV-Y7-FV", "TV-Y7", "TV-14"), release_year = c("31 Mar 1999", "25 Mar 2019", "27 Nov 1996", "2013", "2016", "2017"), date_added = structure(c(18212, 18320, 18212, 17782, 17782, 17417), class = "Date"), duration = c("97 min", "N/A", "103 min", "1 Season", "1 Season", "99 min"), genre = c("Comedy, Drama, Romance", "Animation, Comedy, Family", "Adventure, Comedy, Crime, Family", "Kids' TV", "Kids' TV", "Comedies"), director = c("Gil Junger", "N/A", "Stephen Herek", NA, NA, "Fernando Lebrija"), country = c("USA", "UK, USA, Canada", "USA, UK", "United States", "United States", "United States"), imdb_rating = c("7.3", "6.2", "5.7", NA, NA, NA), platform = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Disney", "Netflix"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 995L, 996L, 997L), class = "data.frame")`

I have tried applying to a subset of the df but has failed to work, as well as applying the `which()` function

Comment: there most certainly is.. but without sample data, desired input and some code to start with, you will probably get very few relevant answers..

Comment: Maybe subset `netflix_and_disney$release_year[1:3]` on both sides of the assignment?

Comment: `netflix_and_disney$release_year[1:3] <-year(dmy(netflix_and_disney$release_year[1:3]))` that seemed to do it! @RuiBarradas

Answer (score 0):

It really all depends on your data and what function you want to apply. But, in principle, you can do this by subsetting your dataframe:

Data:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(
  v1 = rnorm(20),
  v2 = runif(20),
  v3 = sample(20)
)
```

Here we `apply` the function `mean`to the first ten rows of `df`:

```
apply(df[1:10,], 1, mean)
        1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8         9        10 
4.5274415 0.7281229 2.9908109 1.8131179 6.7605775 6.6179570 4.2313168 3.4003004 3.1930399 5.8040552
```

Answer (score 0):

`netflix_and_disney$release_year[1:3] < year(dmy(netflix_and_disney$release_year[1:3]))`

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should also explain **what** the code does and **how** it helps.